# MySQL Query Optimization : Bets and Averages

Tags: mysql, query

I have the following selection string:

```
SELECT * , AVG( `q1` ) AS betavg, COUNT( bet_id ) AS nr, MAX( q1 ) AS qmax, 
(MAX( q1 ) - AVG( `q1` )) AS diff FROM jos_bet_1x3_best GROUP BY `bet_id`
HAVING ( COUNT( `bet_id` ) >2 AND betavg <= q1
AND (qmax - MIN( q1 )) < 0.5 AND q1 <3)
ORDER BY `diff` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Can I optimize this somehow ? I want to select that data where the q1 is bigger than the average.

This is the sample data:

```
+-------+---------------+------+------+------+---------------------+-----------+
| id    | bet_id        | q1   | qx   | q2   | timestamp           | bookie_id |
+-------+---------------+------+------+------+---------------------+-----------+
| 32665 | 4e371a6e23735 | 1.90 | 3.50 | 3.80 | 2011-08-01 21:28:14 |         4 |
| 33410 | 4e371a6e23735 | 2.02 | 3.25 | 3.70 | 2011-08-01 21:28:31 |         8 |
| 34423 | 4e371a6e23735 | 2.05 | 3.25 | 3.25 | 2011-08-01 21:30:08 |         3 |
| 32666 | 4e371a6e23fe8 | 2.20 | 3.25 | 3.20 | 2011-08-01 21:28:14 |         4 |
| 33407 | 4e371a6e23fe8 | 2.17 | 3.20 | 3.35 | 2011-08-01 21:28:31 |         8 |
| 34252 | 4e371a6e23fe8 | 2.20 | 3.25 | 3.25 | 2011-08-01 21:28:52 |         2 |
| 34418 | 4e371a6e23fe8 | 2.05 | 3.25 | 3.30 | 2011-08-01 21:30:08 |         3 |
| 32667 | 4e371a6e24750 | 1.40 | 4.25 | 8.00 | 2011-08-01 21:28:14 |         4 |
| 33406 | 4e371a6e24750 | 1.45 | 4.10 | 7.10 | 2011-08-01 21:28:31 |         8 |
| 34253 | 4e371a6e24750 | 1.40 | 4.20 | 8.50 | 2011-08-01 21:28:52 |         2 |
| 34425 | 4e371a6e24750 | 1.45 | 3.75 | 7.00 | 2011-08-01 21:30:08 |         3 |
| 32668 | 4e371a6e24ee4 | 1.80 | 3.50 | 4.25 | 2011-08-01 21:28:14 |         4 |
| 33462 | 4e371a6e24ee4 | 1.87 | 3.35 | 4.15 | 2011-08-01 21:28:31 |         8 |
| 34251 | 4e371a6e24ee4 | 1.75 | 3.55 | 4.65 | 2011-08-01 21:28:52 |         2 |
| 34420 | 4e371a6e24ee4 | 1.85 | 3.25 | 4.00 | 2011-08-01 21:30:08 |         3 |
+-------+---------------+------+------+------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Finally, I made an other solution based on drex solution:

```
SELECT A. * , ( A.q1 - tb1.betavg) AS diff, tb1.betavg, tb1.nr FROM jos_bet_1x3_best A 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT bet_id, AVG( `q1` ) AS betavg, COUNT( bet_id ) AS nr
        FROM jos_bet_1x3_best GROUP BY `bet_id`
    ) AS tb1
USING ( bet_id ) WHERE tb1.nr >2 AND (A.q1 - tb1.betavg) >0
ORDER BY diff DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I had 'BB.*,AA.q1' which weas wrong. I flipped it to 'AA.*,BB.q1'. Please try again !!!

Comment: Updated it again. Try again, please !!!

Comment: Question : Does your original work ???

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: Question : How many rows should come back ??? I am only getting one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM    jos_bet_1x3_best A
   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT bet_id,
              q1,
              AVG(`q1`) AS betavg,
              COUNT(bet_id) AS nr,
              MAX(q1) AS qmax,
              (MAX(q1) - AVG(`q1`)) AS diff
         FROM jos_bet_1x3_best
       GROUP BY `bet_id`
       HAVING (q1 >= betavg AND nr > 2 AND diff < .5 AND q1 < 3)
        LIMIT 0, 30) AS tb1
   USING (bet_id)
GROUP BY `bet_id`;
```

Please try this.

Comment: I have to admit but THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER !!!

Comment: You get a +1 from me !!!

Comment: I did change your answer a little so that q1 does not appear in the display twice.

Comment: Otherwise it is totally correct. iUngi, please try drex's query.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm just not sure if yours is faster than mine.. i haven't tested it yet thoroughly.

Comment: Acutally, mine does not print 30 rows. Your syntax fits the solution. My syntax has a problem with the HAVING clause. I see yours is right !!!

Comment: This is good, and faster than mine, I figured out that this query is returning only one value which is bigger than the average, but I want all row where the q1 are greater than the average.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE jos_bet_1x3_best ADD INDEX (bet_id,id);
ALTER TABLE jos_bet_1x3_best ADD INDEX (bet_id,q1);
SELECT A.*
FROM
(
    SELECT AA.*,BB.q1 FROM
    (
        SELECT
            bet_id,
            COUNT(1) nr, 
            MAX(q1) qmax,
            AVG(q1) betavg,
            MAX(q1)-AVG(q1) diff
        FROM
            (SELECT bet_id,q1 FROM jos_bet_1x3_best) AAA
        GROUP BY
            bet_id
        HAVING
            (COUNT(1) > 2 AND betavg <= q1 AND
            (qmax-MIN(q1)) < 0.5 AND q1 < 3)
        ORDER BY
            diff DESC LIMIT 0,30
    ) AA INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT bet_id,q1
        FROM jos_bet_1x3_best
    ) BB USING(bet_id)
) A INNER JOIN jos_bet_1x3_best USING (bet_id,q1);
```

Not sure if this will speed things up, but give it a try anyway !!!

Comment: I tried your version, but I'm getting the following error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'q1' in 'having clause'

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Still the same, not working.

Comment: If it's help, this is the database, with data: http://sharetext.org/AZWV

Comment: Looks like drex's query is correct !!!